# non linear least square fitting with the variable as the integration limit

Tags: python, physics, numeric, curve-fitting

I'm trying to make some non-linear fittings with python which involve an integral, and the limits of the integral depends on the independent variable. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import quad


T,M=np.genfromtxt("zfc.txt", unpack=True, skiprows = 0) #here I load the data to fit
plt.plot(T,M,'o')

def arg_int1(x,sigma,Ebm):
    return (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma*Ebm))*np.exp(-(np.log(x/float(Ebm))**2)/(2*sigma**2))
def arg_int2(x,sigma,Ebm):
    return (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma*x))*np.exp(-(np.log(x/float(Ebm))**2)/(2*sigma**2))



def zfc(x,k1,k2,k3):   
    Temp=x*k2*27/float(k2/1.36e-16) 
    #Temp=k2*27/float(k2/1.36e-16) #apparently x can't be fitted with curve_fit if appears as well in the integral limits
    A=sc.integrate.quad(arg_int1,0,Temp,args=(k3,k2))[0]
    B=sc.integrate.quad(arg_int2,Temp,10*k2,args=(k3,k2))[0]
    M=k1*(k2/1.36e-16*A/x+B)
    return M
T_fit=np.linspace(1,301,301)


popt, pcov = curve_fit(zfc,T,M,p0=(0.5,2.802e-13,0.46))

M_fit=np.zeros(301)
M_fit[0]=zfc(100,0.5,2.8e-13,0.46)
for i in range (1,301):    
    M_fit[i-1]=zfc(i,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
plt.plot(T_fit,M_fit,'g')
```

The eror that I get is:

```
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 329, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

which I don't understand, since the function is well defined. I know that the solution of my problem is the feeded parameters (i have made the fit with mathematica). I have tried to look for fitting for the Bloch-Gruneisen function (where the independent variable defines the integral limits as well) but I have not found any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` expects `zfc` to work on array arguments, i.e. given an n-array of x-values and 3 n-arrays of `k1`,`k2`,`k3` values the `zfc(x,k1,k2,k3)` should return an n-array containing the corresponding values of the function. This can however easily be achieved by creating a wrapper for the function using `np.vectorize`:

```
zfc_wrapper = np.vectorize(zfc)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(zfc_wrapper,T,M,p0=(0.5,2.802e-13,0.46))
```

Next time it would be nice if you could provide some sample input data. I managed to run it with test data from some arbitrary function, but this may not always be the case.

Cheers.